# How to extract id value of select element from HTML file in python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am working in python to get HTML id values from the flask webpage. Below is my python code I just want to extract values of ids in the form of a list.

[image: open this image to see code]

The result looks like this for the first 6 id values

["tenure_val", "monthly", "total", "gender","Senior", "Partner"  ]

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the list to be string and use regex to find the ids loading to another list of ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily call ["id"] on each of the element of the list of "input-tags" you got in the `a` variable as shown in your image:

```
id_list = []
for tag in a:
    id_list.append(input["id"])
```

Try playing around with the **[documentation on bs4 attributes](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes)** and other contents!